# Where are stored the settings of each shipping method in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I have two separate e-commerce platforms.

1. A large, old system that drives all the orders and dispatch.
2. An online store powered by WordPress / WooCommerce.

So far, we've managed to automate a lot of simple things like pulling orders from WP, and pushing updated stock levels to it.

One thing I cannot fathom, however, is when I create free_shipping method and set a minimum spend. Where is that stored in the DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can ask to yourself:** Where do Wordpress plugins store their settings?

> The answer is simply the **`wp_options`** table.

If your "Free shipping" **Shipping method ID** is **`free_shipping:10`** you can use:

```
$free_shipping = get_option( 'woocommerce_free_shipping_10_settings' ); 
$min_amount    = $free_shipping['min_amount'];
```

To retrieve the array of data, where `woocommerce_free_shipping_10_settings` is the `option_name`.

The following SQL search query will retrieve all your "Free shipping" methods settings:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'woocommerce_free_shipping%'
```

Comment: And for shipping zone methods, there is the [woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods table](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods).